# Full-width Menubar is not full-width in safari

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, safari, navbar

I have designed the full-width menu-bar, in which menu links is in container and drop-down menu is full width to the browser window. It is working fine in Chrome, firefox, but breaking in safari. The dropdown menu is aligned to the menu to which it is attached and overflowing the right side, leaving left side empty.
here is the css for navbar dropdown:

`.navbar-popup{
    background: #FFF;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 69px;
    overflow: auto;
}`

Can not attach screenshot

Comment: would you show `html` ?

Comment: After digging more, I solved it by changing structure and making it more general effect that will not break in safari. So problem is solved. Thanks.

Comment: If you solved it you could post a solution to your own question.